# Building scripted Jenkins pipeline, error while packaging using Maven

Tags: java, maven, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy

I'm relatively new to DevOps in General as well as Java. Which makes debugging Maven and Jenkins all the more difficult for me.

I am trying to create a scripted Jenkins pipeline for a Java project from the internet using the following script:

```
pipeline{
    agent any
    tools{
        maven 'MAVEN_JENKINS'
    }
    stages{
        stage("checkout from github"){
            steps{
                git branch: 'master',
                url:'https://github.com/redbilledpanda/DevOpsClassCodes.git'
                echo 'pulled from github successfully'
            }
        }
        stage("compile the code to executable format"){
            steps{
                sh "mvn compile"
                echo 'converted the code from human readable to machine readable '
            }
        }
        stage("testing the code"){
            steps{
                sh "mvn test"
                echo 'run and execute the test cases written in selenium'
            }
        }
        stage("code review to check quality of code"){
            steps{
                sh "mvn pmd:pmd"
                echo 'code review done'
            }
        }
        stage("convert the code to package"){
            steps{
                sh "mvn clean package"
                echo 'convert the files to war file'
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The only section that fails is the packaging stage. Here is the entire log:

```
+ mvn package
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[WARNING] 
[WARNING] Some problems were encountered while building the effective model for com.edurekademo.tutorial:addressbook:war:2.0
[WARNING] Reporting configuration should be done in <reporting> section, not in maven-site-plugin <configuration> as reportPlugins parameter. @ line 298, column 40
[WARNING] 
[WARNING] It is highly recommended to fix these problems because they threaten the stability of your build.
[WARNING] 
[WARNING] For this reason, future Maven versions might no longer support building such malformed projects.
[WARNING] 
[INFO] 
[INFO] ----------------< com.edurekademo.tutorial:addressbook >----------------
[INFO] Building Vaadin Addressbook example 2.0
[INFO] --------------------------------[ war ]---------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-enforcer-plugin:1.0:enforce (enforce-versions) @ addressbook ---
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:resources (default-resources) @ addressbook ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] skip non existing resourceDirectory /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/scriptedpipeline/src/main/resources
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.2:compile (default-compile) @ addressbook ---
[INFO] Nothing to compile - all classes are up to date
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:testResources (default-testResources) @ addressbook ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] Copying 1 resource
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.2:testCompile (default-testCompile) @ addressbook ---
[INFO] Nothing to compile - all classes are up to date
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-surefire-plugin:2.19.1:test (default-test) @ addressbook ---

-------------------------------------------------------
 T E S T S
-------------------------------------------------------
Running com.edurekademo.utilities.TestLogger
SLF4J: Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings.
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/var/lib/jenkins/.m2/repository/org/slf4j/slf4j-simple/1.7.7/slf4j-simple-1.7.7.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/var/lib/jenkins/.m2/repository/org/slf4j/slf4j-log4j12/1.7.7/slf4j-log4j12-1.7.7.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#multiple_bindings for an explanation.
SLF4J: Actual binding is of type [org.slf4j.impl.SimpleLoggerFactory]
[pool-1-thread-2] INFO com.edurekademo.utilities.TestLogger - java.lang.ArithmeticException: / by zero
Cause:at com.edurekademo.utilities.TestLogger.testGetErrorMessage2(TestLogger.java:30)
Cause:at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
[pool-1-thread-1] INFO com.edurekademo.utilities.TestLogger - java.lang.ArithmeticException: / by zero
Cause:at com.edurekademo.utilities.TestLogger.testGetErrorMessage1(TestLogger.java:14)
Cause:at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
[pool-1-thread-4] INFO com.edurekademo.utilities.TestLogger - java.io.IOException: TESTIOEXCEPTION
Cause:at com.edurekademo.utilities.ExceptionThrower.doNothing(ExceptionThrower.java:18)
Cause:at com.edurekademo.utilities.TestLogger.testGetErrorMessage4(TestLogger.java:60)
[pool-1-thread-3] INFO com.edurekademo.utilities.TestLogger - java.lang.ArithmeticException: / by zero
Cause:at com.edurekademo.utilities.ExceptionThrower.getCounter(ExceptionThrower.java:13)
Cause:at com.edurekademo.utilities.TestLogger.testGetErrorMessage3(TestLogger.java:45)
[pool-1-thread-5] ERROR com.edurekademo.utilities.ExceptionThrower - java.lang.Exception: DEAR
Cause:at com.edurekademo.utilities.ExceptionThrower.doYYY(ExceptionThrower.java:35)
Cause:at com.edurekademo.utilities.ExceptionThrower.doXXX(ExceptionThrower.java:23)
[pool-1-thread-5] INFO com.edurekademo.utilities.TestLogger - java.lang.Exception: TEST MESSAGE
Cause:at com.edurekademo.utilities.ExceptionThrower.doCheck(ExceptionThrower.java:43)
Cause:at com.edurekademo.utilities.TestLogger.testGetErrorMessage5(TestLogger.java:75)
***** java.lang.Exception: TEST MESSAGE
Cause:at com.edurekademo.utilities.ExceptionThrower.doCheck(ExceptionThrower.java:43)
Cause:at com.edurekademo.utilities.TestLogger.testGetErrorMessage5(TestLogger.java:75)
Tests run: 5, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.031 sec - in com.edurekademo.utilities.TestLogger
Running com.edurekademo.utilities.TestHexAsciiConversion
74657374696e6720617363696920636f6e76657274696f6e20696e746f2068657861646563696d616c
testing ascii convertion into hexadecimal
Tests run: 4, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.026 sec - in com.edurekademo.utilities.TestHexAsciiConversion
Running com.edurekademo.utilities.TestGenericComparator
Tests run: 14, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.016 sec - in com.edurekademo.utilities.TestGenericComparator

Results :

Tests run: 23, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0

[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-war-plugin:2.2:war (default-war) @ addressbook ---
[WARNING] Error injecting: org.apache.maven.plugin.war.WarMojo
com.google.inject.ProvisionException: Unable to provision, see the following errors:

1) Error injecting constructor, java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError: Cannot access defaults field of Properties
  at org.apache.maven.plugin.war.WarMojo.<init>(Unknown Source)
  while locating org.apache.maven.plugin.war.WarMojo

1 error
    at com.google.inject.internal.InternalProvisionException.toProvisionException (InternalProvisionException.java:226)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl$1.get (InjectorImpl.java:1053)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.getInstance (InjectorImpl.java:1086)
    at org.eclipse.sisu.space.AbstractDeferredClass.get (AbstractDeferredClass.java:48)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProviderInternalFactory.provision (ProviderInternalFactory.java:85)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InternalFactoryToInitializableAdapter.provision (InternalFactoryToInitializableAdapter.java:57)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProviderInternalFactory$1.call (ProviderInternalFactory.java:66)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProvisionListenerStackCallback$Provision.provision (ProvisionListenerStackCallback.java:112)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProvisionListenerStackCallback$Provision.provision (ProvisionListenerStackCallback.java:127)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProvisionListenerStackCallback.provision (ProvisionListenerStackCallback.java:66)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProviderInternalFactory.circularGet (ProviderInternalFactory.java:61)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InternalFactoryToInitializableAdapter.get (InternalFactoryToInitializableAdapter.java:47)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl$1.get (InjectorImpl.java:1050)
    at org.eclipse.sisu.inject.Guice4$1.get (Guice4.java:162)
    at org.eclipse.sisu.inject.LazyBeanEntry.getValue (LazyBeanEntry.java:81)
    at org.eclipse.sisu.plexus.LazyPlexusBean.getValue (LazyPlexusBean.java:51)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.DefaultPlexusContainer.lookup (DefaultPlexusContainer.java:263)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.DefaultPlexusContainer.lookup (DefaultPlexusContainer.java:255)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.internal.DefaultMavenPluginManager.getConfiguredMojo (DefaultMavenPluginManager.java:520)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo (DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:124)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.doExecute2 (MojoExecutor.java:370)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.doExecute (MojoExecutor.java:351)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:215)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:171)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:163)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:56)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:294)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:192)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:105)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:960)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:293)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:196)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:568)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:282)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:225)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:406)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:347)
Caused by: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError: Cannot access defaults field of Properties
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.collections.PropertiesConverter.<clinit> (PropertiesConverter.java:46)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.XStream.setupConverters (XStream.java:647)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.XStream.<init> (XStream.java:445)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.XStream.<init> (XStream.java:385)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.XStream.<init> (XStream.java:342)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.war.util.WebappStructureSerializer.<clinit> (WebappStructureSerializer.java:47)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.war.AbstractWarMojo.<init> (AbstractWarMojo.java:316)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.war.WarMojo.<init> (WarMojo.java:49)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0 (Native Method)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance (NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:77)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance (DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstanceWithCaller (Constructor.java:499)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance (Constructor.java:480)
    at com.google.inject.internal.DefaultConstructionProxyFactory$ReflectiveProxy.newInstance (DefaultConstructionProxyFactory.java:126)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorInjector.provision (ConstructorInjector.java:114)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorInjector.access$000 (ConstructorInjector.java:32)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorInjector$1.call (ConstructorInjector.java:98)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProvisionListenerStackCallback$Provision.provision (ProvisionListenerStackCallback.java:112)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProvisionListenerStackCallback$Provision.provision (ProvisionListenerStackCallback.java:127)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProvisionListenerStackCallback.provision (ProvisionListenerStackCallback.java:66)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorInjector.construct (ConstructorInjector.java:93)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorBindingImpl$Factory.get (ConstructorBindingImpl.java:306)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl$1.get (InjectorImpl.java:1050)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.getInstance (InjectorImpl.java:1086)
    at org.eclipse.sisu.space.AbstractDeferredClass.get (AbstractDeferredClass.java:48)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProviderInternalFactory.provision (ProviderInternalFactory.java:85)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InternalFactoryToInitializableAdapter.provision (InternalFactoryToInitializableAdapter.java:57)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProviderInternalFactory$1.call (ProviderInternalFactory.java:66)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProvisionListenerStackCallback$Provision.provision (ProvisionListenerStackCallback.java:112)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProvisionListenerStackCallback$Provision.provision (ProvisionListenerStackCallback.java:127)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProvisionListenerStackCallback.provision (ProvisionListenerStackCallback.java:66)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProviderInternalFactory.circularGet (ProviderInternalFactory.java:61)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InternalFactoryToInitializableAdapter.get (InternalFactoryToInitializableAdapter.java:47)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl$1.get (InjectorImpl.java:1050)
    at org.eclipse.sisu.inject.Guice4$1.get (Guice4.java:162)
    at org.eclipse.sisu.inject.LazyBeanEntry.getValue (LazyBeanEntry.java:81)
    at org.eclipse.sisu.plexus.LazyPlexusBean.getValue (LazyPlexusBean.java:51)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.DefaultPlexusContainer.lookup (DefaultPlexusContainer.java:263)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.DefaultPlexusContainer.lookup (DefaultPlexusContainer.java:255)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.internal.DefaultMavenPluginManager.getConfiguredMojo (DefaultMavenPluginManager.java:520)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo (DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:124)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.doExecute2 (MojoExecutor.java:370)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.doExecute (MojoExecutor.java:351)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:215)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:171)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:163)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:56)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:294)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:192)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:105)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:960)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:293)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:196)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:568)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:282)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:225)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:406)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:347)
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  1.680 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2022-09-28T16:24:30+05:30
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-war-plugin:2.2:war (default-war) on project addressbook: Execution default-war of goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-war-plugin:2.2:war failed: Unable to load the mojo 'war' in the plugin 'org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-war-plugin:2.2' due to an API incompatibility: org.codehaus.plexus.component.repository.exception.ComponentLookupException: Cannot access defaults field of Properties
[ERROR] -----------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] realm =    plugin>org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-war-plugin:2.2
[ERROR] strategy = org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.strategy.SelfFirstStrategy
[ERROR] urls[0] = file:/var/lib/jenkins/.m2/repository/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-war-plugin/2.2/maven-war-plugin-2.2.jar
[ERROR] urls[1] = file:/var/lib/jenkins/.m2/repository/org/apache/maven/reporting/maven-reporting-api/2.0.6/maven-reporting-api-2.0.6.jar
[ERROR] urls[2] = file:/var/lib/jenkins/.m2/repository/org/apache/maven/doxia/doxia-sink-api/1.0-alpha-7/doxia-sink-api-1.0-alpha-7.jar
[ERROR] urls[3] = file:/var/lib/jenkins/.m2/repository/commons-cli/commons-cli/1.0/commons-cli-1.0.jar
[ERROR] urls[4] = file:/var/lib/jenkins/.m2/repository/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-interactivity-api/1.0-alpha-4/plexus-interactivity-api-1.0-alpha-4.jar
[ERROR] urls[5] = file:/var/lib/jenkins/.m2/repository/org/apache/maven/maven-archiver/2.5/maven-archiver-2.5.jar
[ERROR] urls[6] = file:/var/lib/jenkins/.m2/repository/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-io/2.0.2/plexus-io-2.0.2.jar
[ERROR] urls[7] = file:/var/lib/jenkins/.m2/repository/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-archiver/2.1/plexus-archiver-2.1.jar
[ERROR] urls[8] = file:/var/lib/jenkins/.m2/repository/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-interpolation/1.15/plexus-interpolation-1.15.jar
[ERROR] urls[9] = file:/var/lib/jenkins/.m2/repository/junit/junit/3.8.1/junit-3.8.1.jar
[ERROR] urls[10] = file:/var/lib/jenkins/.m2/repository/com/thoughtworks/xstream/xstream/1.3.1/xstream-1.3.1.jar
[ERROR] urls[11] = file:/var/lib/jenkins/.m2/repository/xpp3/xpp3_min/1.1.4c/xpp3_min-1.1.4c.jar
[ERROR] urls[12] = file:/var/lib/jenkins/.m2/repository/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-utils/3.0/plexus-utils-3.0.jar
[ERROR] urls[13] = file:/var/lib/jenkins/.m2/repository/org/apache/maven/shared/maven-filtering/1.0-beta-2/maven-filtering-1.0-beta-2.jar
[ERROR] Number of foreign imports: 1
[ERROR] import: Entry[import  from realm ClassRealm[maven.api, parent: null]]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] -----------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/PluginContainerException
```

The POM file for the project is [here](https://github.com/redbilledpanda/DevOpsClassCodes/blob/master/pom.xml). What exactly is going wrong?

Comment: I tried changing the POM file to reflect the current maven version I have installed on my Linux box but it doesn't seem to help

Comment: What version of Java and maven are you using?

Comment: You're using a rather old version of the maven-war-plugin. In general when a plugin fails with something that's most likely out of your control, the advice is to check for a more recent version. https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-war-plugin/ shows you it is 3.3.2 (at time of writing). You can do this by updating the pom.xml

Comment: @RobertScholte I've tried updating my POM file replacing the plugin version with 3.8.6 but that doesn't seem to help. Are there specific pieces in the POM file that I need to update? Would you please let me know which sections in the POM file to update?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update your pom.xml to include `maven-compiler-plugin` with `maven-war-plugin` latest version. Also, check your java version in the Jenkins project configuration.

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.3.2</version>
</plugin>
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.10.1</version>
    <configuration>
        <source>1.8</source>
        <target>1.8</target>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Answer (score 1):

I see 3 things that might cause this:

1. In your pom, your current compiler is quit old, 3.2:

   ```
       <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.2</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.8</source>
                <target>1.8</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
   ```

Try upgrading this to latest, 3.10.

2. I dont see `maven-war-plugin` in your pom. Try adding it with latest version as well.
3. [Note: Merely setting the target option in the configuration tag does not guarantee that your code actually runs on a JRE with the specified version.](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-compiler-plugin/examples/set-compiler-source-and-target.html)

Try adding this to ensure you are actually compiling using the same version

```
<project>
  [...]
  <properties>
    <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
  </properties>
  [...]
</project>
```

Answer (score 0):

In complement to previous answer :

- Add `maven-compiler-plugin` and `maven-war-plugin` declaration to the `plugin` section in your POM (with latest version). Also explicitly declare the Java version to the maven-compiler-plugin '' section.
- Specify explicitly in your pipeline the Java version used :

```
pipeline {
    agent any
    tools {
        git 'YOUR_GIT_INSTALLATION'
        jdk 'YOUR_JDK_VERSION'
        maven 'MAVEN_JENKINS'
    }
...

}
```

where '**YOUR_GIT_INSTALLATION**' and '**YOUR_JDK_VERSION**' are the one declared in your tool configuration (it is also a good practice to declare explicitly the GIT version and any tools you're using in the pipeline)